# Set Grid width dynamically in code

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a Grid with this columns:

```
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="FirstColumn" Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="SecondColumn" Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

And after I press a button, I want the second column expand to 2*. How can I do this? I tried this but it throws an exception - An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred :(

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var sb = new Storyboard();
        var animation = new DoubleAnimation()
        {
            To = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star).Value,
            From = SecondColumn.ActualWidth,
            EnableDependentAnimation = true
        };
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, "Width");
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, SecondColumn);
        sb.Children.Add(animation);

        sb.Begin();
    }
```

EDIT: I edited the code this way:

```
        var sb = new Storyboard();
        var animation = new ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
        {
            BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0)
        };
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, SecondColumn);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, "Width");
        var keyFrame = new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
        {
            KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
            Value = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star)
        };
        animation.KeyFrames.Add(keyFrame);
        sb.Children.Add(animation);
        sb.Begin();
```

But the animation is not continous, it just wait 2 seconds and jump there. How can I make it continous?

Comment: The value of SecondColumn.Width is GridLength but you want set the double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DoubleAnimation.To` is `Double` type, that we can not set the `GridLength` to the `Double` type.

As lindexi said, we can set the [`GridLength`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.UI.Xaml.GridLength.%23ctor);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) to the `ColumnDefinition.Width`.

> Types such as ColumnDefinition and RowDefinition use GridLength values for some of their properties (ColumnDefinition.Width and RowDefinition.Height ). These property values are used to support variable distribution of available space in layout containers such as Grid (and also derived types of Grid such as VariableSizedWrapGrid ). A GridLength can describe one of three modes for sizing: a fixed width, a weighted distribution (star sizing), or an "Auto" sizing mode.

For more info, please [Grid​Length Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.GridLength#Windows_UI_Xaml_GridLength__ctor_System_Double_Windows_UI_Xaml_GridUnitType_).

If you want use star to the Width, we should be able to set the `GridUnitType.Star` to the `GridLength`.

For example:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SecondColumn.Width = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star);
}
```

If you want to use the `DoubleAnimation`, you should be able to get the Width of the Window and set width that you want to the `DoubleAnimation.To`.

Comment: Thanks, but when I want to use the GridLength in an animation how can I do it? What to use instead of DoubleAnimation?

Comment: @MacakM One type of animation deserves special mention because it's the only way you can apply an animated value to properties that aren't of type Double, Point, or Color. This is the key-frame animation ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames. Please refer the [Discrete object value animations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/graphics/key-frame-and-easing-function-animations#span-iddiscreteobjectvalueanimationsspanspan-iddiscreteobjectvalueanimationsspanspan-iddiscreteobjectvalueanimationsspandiscrete-object-value-animations).

Comment: @MacakM You can minimize the apparent jumps by increasing the number of key frames you declare, but if a smooth animation is your goal, you might be better off using linear or spline key frames instead. But the linear  or spline key frames need to set the double to it, we can not set `GridLength` to it. If you want to make the animation constantly. You should be able get the double type of the ColumnDefinition.Width and set it to the `DoubleAnimation`.

Comment: Yes I tried this at the first place and it didn't work... I made DoubleAnimation from actual width to 2* and it throws me an exception (that was my initial question)

Comment: My mean you can use the SizeChanged event to get the Width of the Window, then you can get the 2/3 Width of the Window. You can set the it to the ColumnDefinition.Width.